# UISegmentedControl - Changing Colors and Size - Not working Right

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I want to be able to Change the Colors and font size of the Segments of a UISegmentedControl.  I'm setting the tag for each segment and then setting the tintColor: forTag: for each of the segments.

Changing the Colors works great, till I pan the control or Pinch it.   In the UIPinchGestureRecognizer code I set the titleTextAttributes to have a different Font Size.  When I do this, the Colors of the Segments revert back to the default Gary Color.

```
- (void)createElement {
if (multiStateControl == nil) {

        //Make our new switch
        //multiStateControl = [UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    multiStateControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Off State Button", @"On State Button", nil]];

     multiStateControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

    [multiStateControl setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f], UITextAttributeFont, 

      nil] 
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

     [multiStateControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f)];

        // Set up the Contents Frame to the same origin as what we were but set the height/width to the new control.
    [elementViewContents setFrame:CGRectMake(elementViewContents.frame.origin.x, 
                                             elementViewContents.frame.origin.y, 
                                             CGRectGetWidth(multiStateControl.frame), 
                                             CGRectGetHeight(multiStateControl.frame))];


        //Set initial use to disabled
    [multiStateControl setOpaque:NO];
        // Set the default title for the button
            [multiStateControl setTag:kTagOffState forSegmentAtIndex:0];
            [multiStateControl setTag:kTagOnState forSegmentAtIndex:1];
            [multiStateControl setTintColor:onColor forTag:kTagOnState];
        [multiStateControl setTintColor:offColor forTag:kTagOffState];  

        // Lets get it on the screen
    [elementViewContents addSubview:multiStateControl];
   [multiStateControl release];

    [self contentSizeChanged];
}       
}
```

//Pinch Gesture

```
-(void) pinchElement:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer  {

    UIFont *existingFont = [[multiStateControl titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal] objectForKey:UITextAttributeFont];

    CGFloat existingFontSize = [existingFont pointSize];
    CGFloat newFontSize = existingFontSize * [gestureRecognizer scale] ;

    [multiStateControl setTitleTextAttributes:
          [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:newFontSize],
          UITextAttributeFont, nil] 
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    [multiStateControl setFrame:CGRectMake(multiStateControl.frame.origin.x, multiStateControl.frame.origin.y, multiStateControl.frame.size.width+20,newFontSize *1.8)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to happen when I don't set the TintColor and then increase the font size of the textAttributes.  It's like the default color is using some standard image for the end caps. When I increase the font, the control grows, then the ends looks stretched. A coworker mentioned the end caps like on a button. It looks like the end apps are stretched to fit the new control size.

My work around was to set the TintColor to a color that is close to the default color, doing this created a new on the fly end cap image (I'm guessing) and all the font scaling works great.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to preserve the color attributes, retrieve them before setting the new font and set them again after setting it.

Comment: That makes sense for the TextColor. I'm not checking that, I'll have to, thanks. Though the Colors that I'm having an issue with are the tintColor of the segments. Is the segment TintColor of the segment hidden inside the TextAttributes?

Comment: looks like tint is not in the attributes, you will have to use the tintColor: method to get them, set the font then use setTintColor: